# NavigateUrl directing to root instead of external website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I know this is probably really easy but when I do this:

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hypGift1" runat="server" visible="true" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("facebook") %>'><asp:Image ID="imgGift1" runat="server" width="55px" ImageUrl="~/files/images/icons/faceyProfile.png" /></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If `Eval("facebook")` is say "www.facebook.com/bla bla" then it trys to go to [www.mysite.com/www.facebook.com/bla](http://www.mysite.com/www.facebook.com/bla) bla

Therefore I tried the following but browser url changes to about:blank#blocked

```
If Not hypGift1.NavigateUrl.Contains("http") Then hypGiftURL.NavigateUrl = "https://" & hypGiftURL.NavigateUrl
```

Comment: The `~` stands for the root.

Comment: Yeah I tried adding ~/ but it didn't work

Comment: I meant for you to remove it.

Comment: Ah, forgot that was still in there from testing. I've took it out and if the url stored is say http://www.facebook.com then it works fine. If it's www.facebook.com then it goes to www.mysite.com/www.facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

Ah sorted. I added // where http didn't exist in the Url like this..

```
If Not hypGiftURL.NavigateUrl.Contains("http") Then hypGiftURL.NavigateUrl = "//" & hypGiftURL.NavigateUrl
```

Comment: You probably want to use `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`.